# Plural tag gesture(s)

Tags: support, stack-overflow, synonym-request

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gesture] (1756 questions) and [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gestures] (529 questions) would seem to be identical.

[Cleanup of singular and plural tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135985/clean-up-of-run-together-hyphenated-and-singular-plural-tags) says to ask a meta question first.  I can not make a **synonym** except through voting and that is not very successful when I have used it.  Do I clean up the tag wikis, move one tag to the other, none or both?

Comment: You don't *need* to ask on meta in cases where it's clear that the synonym is warranted. Given how hard it is to get tag synonyms in place through community votes (and that community votes can only set up the synonym in one direction, which isn't always the right one), what you need is to reach a moderator somehow, which can be done by posting on meta but also by other means such as in chat. Arrange for the tag wiki to be on the tag that becomes the primary name.

Comment: @Gilles How do I talk to a moderator in chat?

Comment: I just mentioned that as a possibility. If you don't hang around in a chatroom where an SO mod hangs out, ask on meta, as you did.